# png file not displaying properly on maps with non PlateCarree projections

Tags: python, cartopy

Have just started working with cartopy for Python and this is my first post on stack overflow. The displayed image of a png file projected onto a PlateCarree projection works fine but the data are skewed and pushed down when I try any other projection. Transform in imshow is set to PlateCarree because lon/lats are regularly spaced in the png image, so I just change the plt.axes projection argument.

I have reviewed various reports on stackoverflow and the examples and tutorials on cartopy webpage. I thought I understood the difference between projection in plt.axes and transform in imshow but I must be missing something.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj=ccrs.Mercator()

img = plt.imread('plot1.png')
img_extent = [-120.0, 70.0, 0.0, 90.0]

ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)

ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', color='black', linewidth=1)

ax.imshow(img, origin='upper',extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

The png represents tropical windstorm frequencies in the North Atlantic. Projects as expected with PlateCarree. With Mercator, for example, the data is pushed down south starting in the Antartic. Looks like the longitudes could be reading correctly but not the latitudes, because it looks like the South Pole is being used to baseline 0 latitude. The image is stretched upwards to the correct Northern Latitudes so the latitude scaling is also not linear (otherwise all the data would appear in the southern hemisphere, based on the extent).

Result using Mercator:

[image: Result using Mercator]

Comment: Just noticed the posted code looks strange -  the 3 imports are all on separate lines in the original code as are img and img_extent lines. Sorry about that and thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You can place 3 backticks on the lines before the import text and then after plt.show() to format your code. I don't think any of the rest of your post needs editing, so good job there.

Comment: I think it is a bug. If you change the extent in imshow to remove the zero value, say  img_extent = [-120.0, 70.0, 1e-10, 90.0], the projections work properly. Tested for Robinson, Mollweide, Mercator and Orthographic. All worked fine.